# Send multiple NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession

I have an `NSURLSession` that looks like this, and what I want to do, is if no data is returned then I want it to try again and again, for up to lets say 8 seconds or 3 attempts and then if still nothing is there, I will have it return no data. Here is what I have now,

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlIn] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
// handle response
    //use my data
    // if no data I want to try again?


}] resume];
```

So I want it to either try 3 times or until 8 seconds has passed. How could I go about doing this,

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Just create properties to keep track of the attempt count and the time that the first attempt was made. Then in completion block increment attempt count and check to see if time elapsed is less than 8 seconds and that the attempt count was less than 3, and if so, call the method that performed this query again. You really should try this yourself. No offense intended, but we're here to help you with your code, not write it for you.

Comment: @Rob That seems like it can get cluttered fast. Do you know of a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: @MendyK - If you're doing this a lot, wrap it in a asynchronous `NSOperation` subclass so you have a nice, encapsulated approach. Or actually look at _why_ it failed and handle it appropriately (i.e. if the network is unreadable, don't bother to try again until Reachability notifies you that the network is back). But these are a little more complicated and the OP hasn't apparently tried anything, so I hesitate to go there until he's tackled the most rudimentary of approaches.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the tip thats what I need to get started, and not offended at all what you said was true. I have put work over the last few hours and got the majority done, if you could just help me with the last bit of checking for if time has passed, I got the timer set up, but just not sure how to do the check cause I have to go to main thread? See answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I am almost there I just have a little bit more to work out with timer. Here is what I have.

I got properties

```
NSInteger attemptInt;
NSInteger _counter;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
```

And then these two methods for my timer

```
- (void)startCountdown
{
    _counter = 8;

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(countdownTimer:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
}

- (void)countdownTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    _counter--;
    if (_counter <= 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
        NSLog(@"8 sec passed");
    }
}
```

And then here is where I am getting my data.

```
- (void)getMenuItems:(NSString*)urlIn{
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlIn] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    //One problem I am facing is I have to call timer for main thread
   if ([date timeIntervalSinceNow] <= 8 && [response expectedContentLength] == 0) {
        attemptInt++;
        [self getMenuItems:url];
    }
    if (attemptInt >= 3) {
        NSLog(@"NO DATA");
    }
    else if ([response expectedContentLength] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"TRY AGAIN");
        attemptInt++;
        [self getMenuItems:url];
    }
    else {
        //GOT MY DATA :)
        self.mealdata=[[MealData alloc]init:data];
    }
```

So I got the attempts worked out am a timer set up I just need some help finishing up to check whether 8 seconds has passed first?

Comment: Excellent first stab at it. Personally, rather than using a timer, I would simply grab the `[NSDate date]` of the start time, and then when I want to check the amount of time elapsed, I would do `[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow]` (that will be a negative value, but the number of seconds that have elapsed). Or you can grab `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` of the start time and then get the difference between the later `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` and the original value. Both of these approaches don't require timers at all and quickly calculate the number of seconds between two points in time.

Comment: @Rob okay I added date, and then tried to check if the `timeIntervalSinceNow` is less than 8 but this didn't work? See addition

Comment: Yep, `[date timeIntervalSinceNow]` will be negative, as the docs say "If the date object is earlier than the current date and time, the this property’s value is negative." Thus flip the sign, e.g. `(-[date timeIntervalSinceNow]) <= 8`. And if it's not doing quite what you expect, insert `NSLog` statements, showing the elapsed time and the `attemptInt`, and you'll quickly diagnose what precisely is going on. (By the way, you can retire all the `NSTimer` stuff.)